# Relationship between weak convergence in $\ell_p$ and norm convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Assume that $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ (weak convergence) in $\ell_p$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$. Show that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(||x_n||_{p}^{p} - ||x_n-x||_{p}^{p}) = ||x||_{p}^{p}.$$

I wonder if this is just a consequence of the fact that this weak convergence implies that $\varphi(x_n) \rightarrow \varphi(x) \,\,\, \forall \varphi\in (\ell_p)^{*}$ and consequence of the Hanh banach theorem, which
$$||x_n||_{p} = \max_{\varphi\in (\ell_p)^{*}, ||\varphi||\leq1} |\varphi(x_n)|$$
and so just apply the limit on those expressions, or do you need more care to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$->$x$ then $||x_n-x||_p$->0.Let ε>0 then there excists an $n_0$ $\in$ $\mathbb N$ so $||x_n-x||_p<ε$ for $n>=n_0$.But then $|||x_n-x||_p-0|<ε$ (since norm is always non negative) for all $n>=n_0$.Also,you have that $||x_n||_p$-->$||x||_p$ since for all n $\in$ $\mathbb N$ you have: $|||x_n||_p-||x||_p|<=||x_n-x||_p$->0.Use all this to get your limit.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however this doesn’t seem to help since I’m talking about convergence in the weak topology.